# Array parameter requires static reference

Tags: java, arrays, static

```
public class Test1
{
    final static int ARR_LENGTH = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
         int[] arr = new int[ARR_LENGTH];
         for(int x=0;x<ARR_LENGTH;x++)
         arr[x]=x+1;

         for(int element:arr)
             System.out.print(element + ", ");
     }
}
```

Why does ARR_LENGTH have to be a static variable when it is declared outside of main?

Answer (score 0):

`static` means that it's a variable of a class,
this means that `static` keyword can be used only in a 'class scope' i.e. it doesn't have any sense inside methods.

Comment: so what would it imply if I declared it without static?

Comment: @r0ckefeller Then you could define your variable non-static as well. But the main() function which starts application is required to be static.

Comment: Read the answer it's marked as a duplicate of. A static method is not associated with an instance of a class, if you want to access non static field from static method, you will have to create a instance of the class and access it through that  instance.

Answer (score -1):

> #### Q: Why does ARR_LENGTH have to be a static variable when it is declared outside of main?

#### Answer: Because main() is an static method.

---

The reason behind this is because static methods and variables can be called before creating an instance of a class (and this is exactly why we define some methods or variables static); Therefore in static methods of a class you can not access non-static members because they are only visible from instances of class not from static methods which could be called before instantiating of same class.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10761460)

Comment: @skypjack I'm quite sure about this is simplest the answer to such question, but for more clarification I added more details about my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Whenever you provide a response, I invite you to put a few details to explain why it solves the issue. It will help the OP and new users.

Comment: @skypjack You're right. Now it get better. :) Thanks for your comments and consideration.